# EhCache NullPointerException issue

Tags: java, caching, ehcache

I am using EhCache to cache some of my content and it works great.
Running heavy performance tests lead sometimes to get `NullPointerException` in different flows.

After doing a research, I understand that EhCache caches objects by reference by default, so I guess my problem is, since after `TTL=60 seconds` the expired element remains in the cache until either :

- a get or remove operation is called on the cache that passes in the same key as the expired element or,
- `evictExpiredElements()` is called

If either of the above actions is performed, Ehcache immediately nullifies the expired element in the cache.

So in my case it seems that the element gets expired during processing of the cached element while other thread tries to get the element which causes the element to be nullified.

My question is what is a decent way to resolve such an issue ?

Comment: Which Ehcache version are you using? (including minor versions0

Comment: And please, add a stacktrace. Ehcache itself should not be the cause of an NPE